# How to use PlantUML plugin in Redmine 5.x?

Tags: redmine, plantuml, redmine-plugins

The [plantuml plugin](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/plantuml) (written by [Michael Skrynski](https://github.com/dkd/plantuml)) is not compatible with Redmine 4.x or later.

How can we use it with Redmine 5.x ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fork which has seemed to make the plugin compatible with a recent version of Redmine:

[javister/plantuml](https://github.com/javister/plantuml)

I checked out the commit [4e7a2e](https://github.com/javister/plantuml/compare/f6a6a81..4e7a2e90540f43a6c5456cc41280a9413ace36a3) from the fork and tried to use it with [Redmica 2.2.3](https://github.com/redmica/redmica/releases/tag/v2.2.3). It worked well.